# Why does Forest in JUNG extend DirectedGraph?

Tags: java, interface, jung

Before I start I am not so good with Graph Theory. However,

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29),

> Any connected graph without simple cycles is a tree. A forest is a
>   disjoint union of trees.

While going through the source code of the JUNG library, I noticed the definition of forest as

```
public interface Forest<V,E> extends DirectedGraph<V,E>
```

Speaking on pure semantic level, is that not incorrect?

OR

Is there some specific reason why its done so? (like makes more sense/easy to understand in some algorithm implementation)

PS: I know that `DirectedGraph` is just a tagging interface and does not declare any function. So, using `DirectedGraph` instead of `UndirectedGraph` does have any consequences (at least I see none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUNG's `Forest` interface defines `getChildren` and `getParent` methods.  These are methods that people generally expect to be associated with trees and forests, and don't make sense unless the graph is directed.

Furthermore, there isn't really a point to having a Forest or Tree interface without such method signatures.  It is true that, in graph theory, a tree is simply a connected acyclic graph.  But there aren't any methods (of general utility, at least) that apply to a tree with undirected edges that don't apply to graphs in general.  That said, you could certainly create an *implementation* of Graph that constrains itself to be a tree with undirected edges--and you are free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Given that JUNG defines a tree to be a directed graph, it certainly makes sense for a forest to be a directed graph as well - a union of directed graphs is a directed graph.

This reduces your question to whether Tree should extend DirectedGraph.  It certainly makes sense that trees are Graphs: they certainly have nodes and edges, and the definition you cited above defines them as a certain class of graphs.  So the question becomes, should trees be directed?

It often makes sense to consider directed trees with edges all pointing to the root (these are used in the union-find algorithm), or with all edges pointing away from the root (search trees are an example).  However, it also makes sense to consider undirected trees (such as the spanning tree of an undirected graph).

It is a little surprising (but not "wrong") to me that the designers chose to specify that all trees are directed without also specifying the relation between the direction of the edges and the tree structure.  That is to say, I think it would be reasonable to simply specify that Tree extends Graph, and let the particular instantiation further specify whether the tree is Directed or Undirected, *or* I would choose a convention (either pointing towards or away from the root) and clearly specify that convention in the javadoc.  The solution the developers have chosen forces the Tree implementers to specify the directions of their edges whole preventing the Tree users from making use of that structure.  For example, if the user knows that all edges point away from the root, they can traverse the graph by starting at the root and visiting all edges going out of the root, but if they don't know that they have to consider both incoming and outgoing edges.

There can be consequences of implementing interfaces that have no methods because of Java's instanceof test.  For example, a graph drawing routine could check whether a graph is an instance of a directed graph, and if so, draw arrows instead of lines.

As a final note, I would be a bit careful about going to Wikipedia or any other source when trying to understand the terminology used in a library, because often different people choose subtly different meanings for things.  For example, in some libraries "Graph" really means "Directed weighted graph".  You are better off going to the javadoc.

Comment: On second reading I noticed this note in the Tree javadoc: "Note that for a tree, there is exactly one unique path from the root to any vertex."  This may mean that all edges are directed away from the root.